# Visual Studio: initialize User control by updating a textbox value from outside the user control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls, vsto

I'm building a VSTO tool for Outlook, that allows reading a certain email and saving it to a specified path.

The thing is I'm getting all the details before initializing a User control that will allow the user to modify some settings, so I can make the code ready for Bulk saving with default settings (No showing the User control)

How can I access/update the text value of the textbox `txtNewFolder` that is on the user control `ctrlSavePath.cs` (named "Save ticket email")?

This is how I toggle the user controll:

```
        private static Tools.CustomTaskPane tpSavePath;

        public static void toggleSavePath(Boolean isForceTurnOn = false,string newFolderPath="")
        {
            CustomTaskPane tpTemp = tpSavePath;
            tpTemp = ControlTogle(tpTemp, "Save ticket email", isForceTurnOn);
        }

        public static Tools.CustomTaskPane ControlTogle(Tools.CustomTaskPane tpTemp,string ControlName, Boolean isForceTurnOn = false)
        {
            //IF IT'S ALREADY INITIALIZED
            if (tpTemp != null)
            {
                //IF WORKBOOK CHANGED, REINIT - DOES NOT APPLY TO OUTLOOK            
                if (tpTemp.Visible == true && isForceTurnOn==false)
                {
                    tpTemp.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    tpTemp.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else //IF NOT INITIALIZED, INITIALIZE
            {
                tpTemp = ControlInit(ControlName);
            }
            return tpTemp;
        }

        private static CustomTaskPane ControlInit(string controlName)
        {
            CustomTaskPane ctrlTemp = null;
            switch (controlName)
            {
                case "Save ticket email":
                    ctrlSavePath cSavePath = new ctrlSavePath();
                    ctrlTemp = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(cSavePath, controlName);
                    ctrlTemp.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
                    ctrlTemp.Width = 500;
                    //ctrlTemp.Height = 500;
                    
                    ctrlTemp.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
            return ctrlTemp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a Ribbon control at an arbitrary moment unless you use Accessibility API, but VSTO won't help you with that. You need to retrieve the control's value when it changes and fires a callback (control specific) that you need to process and remember its value.

In case of an editBox control, you need the `onChange` event. Both the control and the new text will be passed as arguments to your event handler.

If you need to go the other way around and update the text on the control, you need to invalidate the ribbon by calling `RibbonUI.Invalidate()` - Outlook will then fire `getText` callback and you will be able to provide new text for your control.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/7b552756-a970-466d-b7c2-ee5bbe171e34